# Grab a single string value from a method inside class

Tags: c#

I want to get value of `APPname` which returned by method called- `GetProductResearchCredidentials()` and store on a string variable like bellow-

string myVal = //let me know how can i grab value from that method

My Model which returns from method:

```
public partial class EbayAPIProductResearch
    {
        public int EbayAPIID { get; set; }
        public string APPname { get; set; }
        public string DevName { get; set; }
        public string CertName { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> CallLimitExpired { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfRenewal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfFindItemAdvanced { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> FindItemExpired { get; set; }
    }
```

My Method:

```
public class EbayAPIData
    {
        public static Models.EbayAPIProductResearch GetProductResearchCredidentials()
        {
            using (var ctx = new db_zikanalyticsProductionEntities())
            {
                var apis = ctx.EbayAPIProductResearch.ToList();
                foreach (var item in apis)
                {
                    var cestTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time"));
                    if (cestTime > item.DateOfRenewal)
                    {
                        var apiitem = ctx.EbayAPIProductResearch.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EbayAPIID == item.EbayAPIID);
                        apiitem.CallLimitExpired = false;
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                        return apiitem;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unless the veriable is declared at the **class**-level turning it into a **member** of that class, you can´t access a variable declared within a method from outside that method. More general you can´t access any symbol outside the scope where it was defined. However *which* variable do you want to access? I don´t see any `GetProductResearchCredidentials` nor `APPName`.

Comment: how can i get  that single property value from outside that class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you got your item like

```
var item = EbayAPIData.GetProductResearchCredidentials();
```

you can access its properties as

```
item.APPName
```